# Removing a partially installet program using dpkg

Tags: dpkg

I tried to install eToken pkiclient v4.55 for linux from a deb package on Ubuntu 14.04. Ths was installed using software center. As per documentation this deb file was created for ubuntu 7.04 and I could not find a latest version of this client for 14.04. Any way installation is not completed, and I have waited for more then 10 hours for dpkg to complete the task "Adding eToken security provider". When at the end of 10 hours it did not complete this I killed dpkg. Now when ever I try to install any thing dpkg is again stuck at "AddingeToken security provider". So I tried to remove pkiclient using dpkg -r,but I get error that pkiclient is not installed.

So how do I solve this. I just want to make dpkg forget pkiclient and continue with installation.

Comment: Can you provide additional information  - what was a .deb file name ?

Comment: name of the deb file was pkiclient-full_4.55-33_i386.deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find installed package name with command in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -l pkiclient-full*
```

Uninstall package with --purge parameter

```
sudo dpkg --purge [package name]
```

My wild guess is that package name is pkiclient-full, example command is

```
sudo dpkg --purge pkiclient-full
```

If purge does not work you will have to skip prerm and postrm scripts which is messy and it is not recomended. Scripts are located in /var/lib/dpkg/info folder with name pkiclient-full.prerm and pkiclient-full.postrm.

So I would suggest that you first move /var/lib/dpkg/info/pkiclient-full.prerm if exists to your home directory, create empty prerm script and set executable bit with commands

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/pkiclient-full.prerm ~/
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/info/pkiclient-full.prerm
sudo chmod +x /var/lib/dpkg/info/pkiclient-full.prerm
```

Do the same for pkiclient-full.postrm if exists

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/pkiclient-full.postrm ~/
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/info/pkiclient-full.postrm
sudo chmod +x /var/lib/dpkg/info/pkiclient-full.postrm
```

After try to purge package with command

```
sudo dpkg --purge pkiclient-full
```

Comment: Yes you are right, the name pkiclient-full is correct. Now dpkg is stuck at removing "Removing eToken security provider". I will wait for some time and report back.

Comment: After waiting for more then 6 hours I interrupted purge. Any other ideas to remove this program

Comment: I have modified answer and added another solution - modify package prerm and postrm scripts.